# How to post bulk messages in yammer?

Tags: yammer

I am trying to post multiple messages in Yammer through only one account.

I have a service account on Yammer. Through that service account I want to post multiple messages on behalf of multiple users, but the REST API of Yammer has rate limits.

Is there is any way to post multiple messages without any hurdle of rate limits?

Comment: Why do you think they have rate limits?  Why do you need to exceed those limits?  I can't help but think "spammer".

Answer (score 0):

The rate limits cannot be exceeded, you'll get a 429 error for Too Many Requests. The rate limits are per app per user, so if you have a legitimate reason for posting a lot of messages in a very short amount of time, some creative thinking around these boundaries can help.